# "imagio.imsave" vs "imageio.core.util.Array.tofile"

Tags: python, image-processing

I am expanding my limited Python knowledge by converting some MATLAB image analysis code to Python.  I am following [Image manipulation and processing using Numpy and Scipy](http://scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing).  The code in Section 2.6.1 saves an image using both `imageio.imsave` and `face.tofile`, where `type(face)=<class 'imageio.core.util.Array>'`.

I am trying to understand why there are two ways to export an image.  I tried web-searching `tofile`, but got [numpy.ndarray.tofile](https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html).  It's very sparse, and doesn't seem to be specific to images.  I also looked for `imageio.core.util.Array.tofile`, but wasn't able to find anything.

Why are there two ways to export files?  And why does `imageio.core.util.Array.tofile` seem to be un-findable online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in *what* the two functions write in the file.

`imageio.imsave()` saves a conventional image, like a picture or photo, in JPEG/PNG format that can be viewed with an image viewer like **GIMP**, `feh`, `eog`, **Photoshop** or MSxPaint.

[tofile()](https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) saves in a Numpy-compatible format that only Numpy (and a small number of other Python tools) use.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Is there a systematic way to know *what* to look for when seeking documentation? Based on `type(face)=<class 'imageio.core.util.Array>'`, it seemed like I needed to find `imageio.core.util.Array.tofile`. Based on your answer, it seems instead that [numpy.ndarray.tofile](https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) might be the right page.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any suggestions. I just save bookmarks when I find relevant stuff. I know it's not much help, but a lot if it comes from practicing.